# leaflet pane style.pointerEvents = none

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I tried the Interactive Choropleth Map Example form https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/
added a geocoder that places a circle.
But the circle overlays my geojson layer and therefore clicking and hover dosen't work anymore in this area.
I checked out panes tutorial an try to adapt to it. But still not clickable.
Here is a jsfriddle for demonstration https://jsfiddle.net/fhepqrnz/1/
Use the search (right corner) to search for NewYork. Then the circle is drawn. But the state in this area is not anymore highlighted.

```
    // Search
    map.createPane('searchradius');
    map.getPane('searchradius').style.zIndex = 650;
    map.getPane('searchradius').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    var geocoder = L.Control.geocoder({
      defaultMarkGeocode: false
    })
      .on('markgeocode', function(e) {
          console.log(e.geocode);
        var center = e.geocode.center;
        var circle = L.circle(center, {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0,
        radius: 15000,
        pane: 'searchradius'
        }).addTo(map);
        map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
      })
      .addTo(map);
```

Glad if someone have the answer for this.

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#interactive-layer-interactive

Comment: Hi Ivan, 
The Mouseover / clicking works but the layer above blocks it. Or is there something else that you like to point out with the reference to events documentation?

Comment: I'm not pointing to the events documentation. I'm pointing to the documentation about the `interactive` option which is inherited by circles.

Answer (score 1):

Tanks to the hint of @IvanSanchez i figured it out.

The **interactive: flase** is the key

```
  .on('markgeocode', function(e) {
      console.log(e.geocode);
    var center = e.geocode.center;
    var circle = L.circle(center, {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0,
    radius: 15000,
    pane: 'searchradius',
    interactive: false
    }).addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
  })
```